# Google Translate messes up Font Awesome Icons

Tags: font-awesome, google-translate

I use font awesome icons on my website. (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

I am also thinking of adding the google translate widget to my website as a little tab at the bottom that prompts the user to translate the page if they need to. (https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)

However, if I run my site through google translate, all of the font awesome icons gets messed up. I'm thinking that google tries to translate the icons (since it's essentially just a font type). Does anyone have an idea to prevent this from happening?

You can see an example by just running the font awesome site through google translate. (https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=es&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffortawesome.github.io%2FFont-Awesome%2F)

Google Translate + Font Awesome = Not Awesome

Answer (score 2):

Apparently (untested) you can add `class="notranslate"` to your stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" class="notranslate" />
```

Comment: I've also tried this and it still doesn't seem to work. At this point, I think it's impossible to have font awesome work with google translate.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an attribute to your HTML like this:

```
<div translate="no">Let's keep this in plain English!</div>
```

or add a CSS class:

```
<div class="notranslate">Let's keep this in plain English, too!</div>
```

Both is possible, but the first one is W3C recommended and can by viewed in detail here: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-translate-flag.en

**UPDATE:**

The above examples only work for text inside of HTML attributes. It does not include CSS content in the pseudo ::before attribute.

So, just include the fontawesome library through CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those ideas work for font awesome text...=( Your first suggestion works for regular text in html elements though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "notranslate" class where You have the problem, for example in my case the problem was in all material-icons, then I added "notranslate" class to all material icons using Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".material-icons").addClass("notranslate");
});
```