# @font-face and Google Translate

Tags: css, fonts, translate

I have an annoying problem with @font-face fonts/code and Google Translate. It seems that Google Translate block display/usage of external fonts.

The script itself is nothing special - just a code generated by Font Squirrel, which works fine, except when Google Translate is used.

Can you please give me info how can I diagnose and/or fix this?

Or maybe is there any known issue with custom font display with Google Translate.

Thanks!

Comment: Add attribute `translate="no"` - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29053605/560287

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose? I do _need_ Google Translate to work, but I would preffer it to work _with_ fonts.